# C# Entity Framework beginner question

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm in the early stages of learning to use Entity Framework 4.1 using the book "Programming Entity Framework" using C# in VS2010. I've run into a problem that's probably obvious to an experienced EF programmer.

[image: Screen shot of VS2010 editor]

*“System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

The ‘contacts’ fields are identified correctly in the pop-up help, but trying to access those fields generates the error shown above. While typing in ‘contacts’, the pop-up fields list does not contain any of the underlined fields.

I don’t understand this inconsistency and would welcome your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var contacts = (from c in context.Person_Contacts
               where c.FirstName == "Robert"
               select new { c.Title, c.FirstName, c.LastName }).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", contacts.Title, contacts.FirstName, contacts.LastName);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Try that

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! The error message seems misleading (as 'contacts' does indeed contain a definition for 'Title'). Can you explain that to me?

Comment: As an aside, this example was taken verbatim from “Programming Entity Framework”. Just one of *many* errors I’ve found in the sample code.

Comment: Because it does have the Title property in there but the object you were getting was an array (IEnumerable) (IQueryable). So you first have to let it know you only want the first result.. or else you will need to loop through your object

Comment: Pardon me, but this example is not "verbatim" from the book. The problem with your example, is that you need to iterate through the results in the way that J.Tihon shows you. Evan's will work but it will only give you one and you'll miss out if there are more than one Roberts in the database.

Comment: @Julie Lerman - your book only showed the LINQ code as an example of a query; it did not show how to display the result. In other words, your example was correct and my attempt at displaying the result is what was wrong.

Comment: @Julie Lerman - my comment above regarding the number of sample code errors was also in error. Somehow I was using a similar but different database (from the first edition perhaps); the entity names in the database I was using differed from those in your sample code. My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

`contacts` is of type `IQueryable` which itself implements `IEnumerable`, so whtat you are actually looking at, is a collection of contacts, not a single one. But you trying to access a specific contact within the list.

You can either wrap you `Console.WriteLine` method in a foreach loop to print out all contacts, like so:

```
foreach (var contact in contacts.ToList()) // ToList will cause EF to perform the SQL query and load the complete results in a list.
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", contact.Title, contact.FirstName, contact.LastName);
}
```

If you are only looking for a single contact, you can use either the First(), Last() or Single() method, which will return the corresponding entity.

```
var contact = contacts.FirstOrDefault(); // Get the first contact with the specified name or a null-reference if the query has no results:

if (null != contact)
{
    Console.WriteLine(...)
}
```